# Set multiple colors for bargraphitem in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

I have a list from 0 to 19, which will be the values of y-axis and a list with different values which will be the WIDTH of the different bars (horizontal bar graph).

```
    x=[5.509, 5.509, 5.414, 5.414, 5.414, 5.289, 5.289, 5.289, 5.289, 5.289, 5.289, 5.289, 5.174, 5.174, ...]
    y=['RUS', 'VET', 'OCO', 'MSC', 'MAZ', 'VER', 'HAM', 'BOT', 'GAS', 'STR', 'SAI', 'RAI', 'NOR', 'PER', ...]
    y_list[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, ...]
```

On the other hand, I have a dictionary, whose keys are the codes of the driver ('PER','TSU'...) and the values are the hexadecimal color.

```
driver_colors ={'VER': '#0600ef', 'HAM': '#00d2be', 'BOT': '#00d2be', 'PER': '#0600ef', 'SAI': '#dc0000', 'NOR': '#ff8700', 'LEC': '#dc0000', 'RIC': '#ff8700', 'GAS': '#2b4562', 'ALO': '#0090ff', 'OCO': '#0090ff', 'VET': '#006f62', 'STR': '#006f62', 'TSU': '#2b4562', ...}
```

I tried to make a for loop:

```
p1=graph_Widget.addPlot(title=graph_title)
for item in y_list:
    bargraph=pg.BarGraphItem(x0=0,y=y_list[item], width=x[item], height=0.6, brush=driver_colors[y[item]])
    p1.addItem(bargraph)
```

But it wont let me put a single item (y=y_list[item]), since it asks for a list which has *len* attribute.

I can't think of any other way to put the whole list and change the value of the brush at the same time.

This is the result I get when I put the two lists and a unique color:

[image: Bar graph]

Answer (score 2):

You're right, the call requires lists.
You do not actually need `y_list` in this case. Just provide a monotonic range. The key to coloring the bars with your desired colors is to use the `brushes` kwarg.

Drop your loop and try the following:

```py
bargraph = pg.BarGraphItem(x0=0, y=range(len(x)), width=x, height=0.6,
                           brushes=[driver_colors[driver] for driver in y])
p1.addItem(bargraph)
```

I don't have the rest of your code that labels each bar with the driver's name, but I was able to at least generate bars of various lengths and colors.

p.s. `BarGraphItem` is one of the more poorly documented items in the PyQtGraph API, but if you look at its [source code](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/BarGraphItem.html#BarGraphItem) you will recognize how the `brushes` kwarg is used.

Comment: It works exactly as intended, thank you so much
https://i.imgur.com/qh6WSd1.png

Comment: Are you able to mark this as the answer @moy?