# How to plot stacked bar graphs with different number of values

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have read [Set multiple colors for bargraphitem in pyqtgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992950/set-multiple-colors-for-bargraphitem-in-pyqtgraph) and it was very useful, however, in that example all the arrays have the same number of values.
I have multiple arrays, and not all of them have the same amount of values.
[Here you can see the arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9JCH.png) . See that MAZ exists in the first, but not in the second one.

I wanted my graph to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCUES.png)

What I have so far is this:

```
import numpy as np
import fastf1 as ff1
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pandas as pd
import json, requests
import collections
from  PyQt5 import QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
ff1.Cache.enable_cache('./cache')
race=ff1.get_session(2021,1,'R')
r = requests.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2021.json")
r = json.loads(r.text)
laps=race.load_laps(with_telemetry=True)
drivers=pd.unique(laps['Driver'])
stints_driver= laps[['Driver','Stint','Compound','LapNumber']].groupby(['Driver','Stint','Compound']).count().reset_index()
stints_driver = stints_driver.rename(columns={'LapNumber': 'StintLength'})
stints_driver = stints_driver.sort_values(by=['Stint'])
stints_driver.set_index('Driver')
compound_colors = {
    'SOFT': '#FF3333',
    'MEDIUM': '#FFF200',
    'HARD': '#EBEBEB',
    'INTERMEDIATE': '#39B54A',
    'WET': '#00AEEF',
}
stintlist=collections.defaultdict(list)
for k in range(int(max(stints_driver['Stint']))):
    stintlist[k+1]=stints_driver.where(stints_driver['Stint']==k+1).dropna()

window = pg.plot()
start=np.zeros(len(drivers))

start=np.zeros(len(stintlist[1]))
# for t in range(int(max(stints_driver['Stint']))): 
    # bargraph=pg.BarGraphItem(x0=start,y=range(len(stintlist[t+1])),width=stintlist[t+1]['StintLength'],height=0.6, brushes=[compound_colors[compound] for compound in stintlist[t+1]['Compound']])
bargraph=pg.BarGraphItem(x0=start,y=range(len(stintlist[1])),width=stintlist[1]['StintLength'],height=0.6, brushes=[compound_colors[compound] for compound in stintlist[1]['Compound']])
window.addItem(bargraph)  
QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()  
    # start=np.add(start,stintlist[t+1]['StintLength'])
```

[I could plot the first array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9yiZ.png) but the moment it changes its size the code does not work any more. I had to do the ***start*** numpy array with the length of the first element of stintlist because it wouldn't let me add later the StintLength if it had a different length.

Note that I commented a few lines in order to get some output, but they are necessary for the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Your problem properly, You want to plot stacked bar plot of different colors for each Driver across all stint lists.
To get this effect, You can't just plot whole list of stints in a chunk. Like that You will plot just n bars with one constant x offset.
What You want is different X offset for each Driver in one bar plot with different color based on Compound.

I've prepared code, based on Your example, which plots multi-color bar plot for each Driver in each chunk (list of drivers). I'm calculating x offset for previous driver in previous chunk and use it as a x0 for next one. Like that You can achieve effect of stacked multi colored bar plot.

Even if it's not Your final solution, it might help You to get there.

Here is the code:

```
import collections
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import fastf1 as ff1
import pandas as pd
import pyqtgraph as pg
import requests

ff1.Cache.enable_cache('./cache')
race = ff1.get_session(2021, 1, 'R')
r = requests.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2021.json")
r = json.loads(r.text)
laps = race.load_laps(with_telemetry=True)
drivers = pd.unique(laps['Driver'])
stints_driver = laps[['Driver', 'Stint', 'Compound', 'LapNumber']].groupby(
    ['Driver', 'Stint', 'Compound']).count().reset_index()
stints_driver = stints_driver.rename(columns={'LapNumber': 'StintLength'})
stints_driver = stints_driver.sort_values(by=['Stint'])
stints_driver.set_index('Driver')
compound_colors = {
    'SOFT': '#FF3333',
    'MEDIUM': '#FFF200',
    'HARD': '#EBEBEB',
    'INTERMEDIATE': '#39B54A',
    'WET': '#00AEEF',
}
# Generate data
stintlist = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k in range(int(max(stints_driver['Stint']))):
    stintlist[k + 1] = stints_driver.where(stints_driver['Stint'] == k + 1).dropna()

window = pg.plot()
# Collect X offset for each driver
offsets = OrderedDict()
bar_height = 0.6
# Bar height + 0.1 offset
bar_height_total = 0.7
for chunk_index, stint_chunk in stintlist.items():
    for index, row in stint_chunk.iterrows():
        driver = row["Driver"]
        x_offset = offsets.get(driver, 0)
        bar_width = row["StintLength"]
        # Calculate width of all bars (which is offset for next bar of that Driver)
        offsets[driver] = x_offset + bar_width
        # Crate new bar for Driver, start plot at the end of already plotted bar (x_offset)
        # Y position is index of Driver in offset dict
        bar_graph = pg.BarGraphItem(x0=[x_offset], y0=[list(offsets.keys()).index(driver) * bar_height_total],
                                    width=bar_width, height=bar_height,
                                    brush=compound_colors.get(row["Compound"], "#336699"))
        window.addItem(bar_graph)

QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: This works exactly as I intended, I didn't know you could plot row by row, I thought you had to pass the entire list in order to get a stint. Thank you